# CSS calc() in Safari with float values

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

I have a problem with the CSS function `calc` in Safari.

I have following code: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lugw0zq/1/

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  width: 120.77px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  left: 12px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

In Chrome / Firefox you will see a black box and smaller red box in its left, while in Safari there will be an additional thin red line in the right part of the box.

Notice how the parent container's width has a float value (120.77px). The child container's width is calculated with `calc(100% - 12px)` what results in 108px instead of 108.77px in Safari - obviously due to integer parsing.

How can I prevent Safari from showing this thin line?

Comment: Exactly what does 0.77 of a pixel look like? I'm guessing this is due to different pixel rounding and renders between browsers.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, sure it does. And it get's displayed rounded. But Safari also seem to calculate rounded (floored), but Firefox and Chrome do it with the float value.

Comment: Well you have an unusual `calc` function going on...perhaps you could explain what the **actual** problem is.

Comment: @Paulie_D The actual problem is the red line you can see in Safari. I don't want that line to be visible. The child component shall be exactly as big as the parent one (subtracted by an amount of px - that's why I use CSS's `calc()`). And what do you mean with "you have an unusual calc function"? I use the regular calc function of CSS.

Comment: `100%-0` is unusual....is what I mean. And anything greater than 0 wouldn't have the issue as such since the 'space' would all be red.

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh, I see. That's just a value to represent clearly what's happening. Of course I'm using a different value in my code. And the problem stays the same because I'm tilting the child component a bit to the right, so that it shall(!) fit to the border.

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited my code snippet to show what I mean. I hope that clarifies it.